# Inserting a multi-dimensional php array into a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have an array from a csv with a similar structure to this:

```
$array = array(
    array('name', 'age', 'gender'),
    array('Ian', 24, 'male'),
    array('Janice', 21, 'female')
);
```

I would like to insert it into a MySQL table where the items of the first array (name, age, gender) are the column titles and each subsequent array is a row in the table.

Could anyone advise as to the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code will work, but it assumes that the length of all nested arrays is the same, in other words that each nested array contains values for all the attributes defined in the first nested array.

```
$array = array(
    array('name', 'age', 'gender' ),
    array('Ian', 24, 'male'),
    array('Janice', 21, 'female')
);

$fields = implode(', ', array_shift($array));

$values = array();
foreach ($array as $rowValues) {
    foreach ($rowValues as $key => $rowValue) {
         $rowValues[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($rowValues[$key]);
    }

    $values[] = "(" . implode(', ', $rowValues) . ")";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO table_name ($fields) VALUES (" . implode (', ', $values) . ")";
```

This solution will work with any number of attributes defined in the first nested array, as long as all other nested arrays have the same length. For the array above the output will be:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name, age, gender) VALUES (Ian, 24, male), (Janice, 21, female)
```

For a demonstration see http://codepad.org/7SG7lHaH, but note that I removed the call to mysql_real_escape_string() on codepad.org, because they do not allow the function. In your own code you should use it.

Comment: once you use implode to place these in the database, how can you explode them out to the original array that you had before? I am currently dealing with the same problem

Comment: Unknown column 'Ian' in 'field list'

here is your output.Code is Not working

Answer (score 1):

```
$fields = implode(',', array_shift($array)); // take the field names off the start of the array

$data = array()
foreach($array as $row) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($row[0]);
    $age = (int) $row[1];
    $gender = mysql_real_escape_string($row[2]);
    $data[] = "('$name', $age, '$gender')";
}

$values = implode(',', $data);

$sql = "INSERT INTO yourtable ($fields) VALUES $values";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

That should produce a query string like:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (name, age, gender) VALUES ('Ian', 24, 'male'), ('Janice', 21, 'female'), etc....
```

Comment: one issue may be that the variables, $name $age $gender will be different each time and the number of them will be different so would I be able to get the variable name from the first array? something like count the elements in the first array then increment it. So the variable would be something like - $data[0][$x] ?

Comment: As long as the FIRST row in the array contains the fieldnames, and the 2nd, 3rd, etc.. rows have the values, then this function will handle any number of rows. up to PHP's memory limits and whatever point the query string grows to exceed mysql's max_allowed_packet limit.

Comment: @MarcB I think he's talking about different number of field, not row.

Comment: @Aurelio: ah. gotcha. in that case, no, this chunk of code only does 3 fields.

Comment: yes sorry, I may not have been clear. As I won't always know the number and title of fields. So I think Aurelio's code will do that. Thanks

Comment: @chentudou: just be careful with the string values. Any quotes in any of them will break the generated query. That's why I hardcoded the 3 values and used mysql_real_escape_string. It **IS** possible to perform an sql injection attack on yourself.

Comment: @MarcB: Added an int cast to prevent that for non-string fields, too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value in the array are **TRUSTED** and **SECURE**.

```
$count = count($array);
$keys = $array[0];

for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++)
{
   $query = "INSERT INTO tablename (" . implode(",", $keys) . ") VALUES ('" . implode ("','", $array[$i]) . "');";
   $query = str_replace(',)', ')', $query);
   mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: quoting the fieldnames turns them into strings and they won't be treated as field names anymore. Otherwise, looks good for the most part.

Comment: do you know why I may be getting an 'invalid arguments passed' warning with this code on implode()?

Comment: @chentudou Are you sure you copied good the code? I tried it before I post and works good. Besides, as you can see, this code will work also if there are more (or less) then 3 field.

Comment: i tried again... the implode warning has gone but it says there is an error in the SQL syntax. I will keep trying, may be my mistake.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: You swapped the parameters for implode. Edited.

Comment: @chentudou You can check that the code works here (and you can also copy the source): http://codepad.org/CuRp4pzC

Comment: @hakre Many thanks. The funny thing is that the code still works if you swap them as you can see here: http://codepad.org/5KSZmBTD :)

Comment: Yes, right, that has historic reasons, but better put the delimiter as first, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php ;)

Comment: unfortunately I still can't get this to put the data into the mysql table. I am not seeing any error message now, but no data appears. Is this likely to be a problem with my database setup?

Comment: @chentudou It is hard to say but the code works good as you can see in the link I gave. Anyway, I think you can open another question to solve this different issue.

Comment: The code in my answer will produce a single query that will achieve the same result. For large arrays, and thus many inserts, it is a nice optimization.

Answer (score 0):

for this array you could do something as simple as this:

```
$array = csv_array(); // this is your array from csv

$col_name = $array[0][0];
$col_age = $array[0][1];
$col_gender = $array[0][2];

for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++){
    //this is where your sql goes
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table` ($col_name, $col_age, $col_gender) 
    VALUES($array[$i][0], $array[$i][1], $array[$i][2])";

    $db->query($sql);
}
```

You should sanitize input, which I didn't do in my example. If your array structure isn't guaranteed to be the same then you'll have to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
$rows = array(
    array('name', 'age', 'gender'),
    array('Ian', 24, 'male'),
    array('Janice', 21, 'female')
);

$columns = array_shift($rows);

$rows = array_map(function($row) {
    /*
     * TODO: escape column values
     */

   return '"' . implode('", "', $row) . '"';
}, $rows);

$sql = 'INSERT  INTO ...
                (' . implode(', ', $columns) . ')
        VALUES  (' . implode('), (', $rows) . ')';
```

As mysql (extension) will "cast" your values on insert, you don't need to pay attention of the column types: if the column is defined as integer, in the database, it will be inserted as integer, even if you quote the value (for example: the age).

Pay attention on the TODO i marked in the source: it is very unsafe to insert values, without escaping them (SQL injection).

Answer (score 0):

My solution in 2 aproaches.

1. Save the array values as serialized representations of the data in a simple DB table.
2. Save the array values in separate table fields.

Working example:

```
$array = array(
    0 => array ( "name", "age", "gender"),
    1 => array ( "Ian", "24", "male"),
    2 => array ( "Janice", "21", "female")
);

foreach($array as $key1 => $value1){
    foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2){
        // assuming the first element (0) in the array is the header value and the header value is a valid array key
         if($key1 > 0){
              $items[$key1-1][ $array[0][$key2] ] = $value2;
         }
    }    
}

// 1. store values as serialized representation
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO datatable SET data = ".mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($value))."";
    echo $sql.PHP_EOL;
}

// 2. auto create fields in database and store values
foreach ($array[0] as $key1) {
    $sql = "ALTER TABLE forms ADD '".$key1."' TEXT NOT NULL";
    echo $sql.PHP_EOL;
}
foreach ($items as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO datatable SET ".$key2." = '".mysql_real_escape_string($value2)."'";
        echo $sql.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Array**

```
$arrayData = array(
     array(
        'name' => 'Paul',
        'age' => 28,
        'gender' => 'male',


    ),
     array(

        'name' => 'Rob',
        'age' => 23,
        'gender' => 'male',


    )
);

 foreach($arrayData as $data){

        $query = "INSERT INTO persons (name,gender,age)
        VALUES ('$data[name]', '$data[gender]',  $data[age])";

        //echo $query;die;
            mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            //exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this kind of thing is by using prepared statements and transactions with the help of PDO library. PDO is the simplest choice for any DB interaction in PHP.

Prepared statements are fast, easy and they offer parameter binding which will protect you from SQL injection as a side effect.

DB transactions ensure that all the data is inserted or none at all. They can also significantly improve the performance of such kind of task.

Here is an example code:

```
// create new connection to MySQL using PDO class
$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset", $user, $pass, [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);

$array = array(
    array('name', 'age', 'gender'),
    array('Ian', 24, 'male'),
    array('Janice', 21, 'female')
);

// discard the header row (1st row) from the array
array_shift($array);

// start transaction
$pdo->beginTransaction();

// prepre SQL statemenet with 3 placeholders
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO csv_table(name, age, gender) VALUES(?,?,?)');
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $stmt->execute($row);
}

// end transaction
$pdo->commit();
```

#### What about the header row?

As you can see in the code above I am discarding the header row. Since SQL tables are rigid I need to know beforehand what are the names of columns. If you want to match columns in the CSV to the columns in your schema dynamically then you need to add some logic which will look at a hardcoded list of columns (you can also fetch this information from `information_schema`) and match it with the names of columns from your CSV.

The code can be adjusted as follows. Iterate over the column names from CSV and throw an exception if any of the columns are not defined in your code. If all columns are verified then `implode()` the column names and inject that into your SQL string.

```
$array = array(
    array('name', 'age', 'gender'),
    array('Ian', 24, 'male'),
    array('Janice', 21, 'female')
);

$table_columns = ['age', 'gender', 'name'];

// Validate CSV header row (1st row) against your schema columns
$header = array_shift($array);
foreach ($header as $col_name) {
    if (!in_array($col_name, $table_columns, true)) {
        throw new \Exception('Incorrect column name specified in CSV file');
    }
}

// start transaction
$pdo->beginTransaction();

// prepre SQL statemenet with 3 placeholders
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO csv_table('.implode(',', $header).') VALUES(?,?,?)');
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $stmt->execute($row);
}

// end transaction
$pdo->commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most direct way to insert a multi array to SQL, could be:

```
$queryIn = "INSERT INTO table (resultsArray) values (" . print_r($multiArray, true) . "')";
```

That works.