# Generate grouped comma seperated list from multidimensional array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to do a bulk insert to MySQL so I need to end up with the values in this format:

`(1,2,2),(1,2,8),(1,2,0)`

Currently I can generate a multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 1
            [key2] => 2
            [key3] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 1
            [key2] => 2
            [key3] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 1
            [key2] => 2
            [key3] => 0
        )

)
```

What is the most efficient method to convert the array to the 'grouped comma seperated list' that I need?

Comment: Relevant: [Inserting a multi-dimensional php array into a mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7746720/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something like this, presuming you don't need to worry about escaping commas and parentheses in your data.

```
foreach ($arrays as &$array) {
    $array = '('.implode(',', $array).')';
}

$csv = implode(',', $arrays);
```

Comment: Hi derp. This is the kind of mind bending magic I was hoping for. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating the array into a string for the insert.

```
foreach($array as $a){
    $output .= '('.$a['key1'].','.$a['key2'].','.$a['key3'].'),';
}

$output = substr($output, 0, -1); // remove the last comma
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... how would this handle the commas separating the groups???

Comment: Ah, just added commas between groups and used substr to remove the trailing comma

Comment: Thanks for fixing that! It works good but it was I was hoping to avoid   describing the individual keys. Points for an otherwise workable solution!

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use php's `implode` function?

In this case I'd do two loops:

```
    $gather=array(); //here we will keep all single arrays
    $multi=array(array('1','2','3'),array('4','5','6'));

    foreach($multi as $single)
    {
    $gather[]="(".implode($single,',').")";
    }

    print_r(implode(",",$gather)); //(1,2,3),(4,5,6)
```