# Inserting both Key and value of a multi-dimensional array into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 5410
            [Issue] => 201
            [volume] => 2
            [pages] => 105-9
            [authors] => Onger, M., Jaluth, K.
            [publication_date] => 17 January 2016
            [journals] => Nature Medicine
            [link_to_pubmed] => http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 5411
            [Issue] => 301
            [volume] => 7
            [pages] => 32-9
            [authors] => Onger, M., Jaluth, K.
            [publication_date] => March 30
            [journals] => Lancet
            [link_to_pubmed] => http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2
        )
        )
```

I have been cracking my head the whole day trying to figure out how i can insert both the key and the value to get something that looks like this

```
+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key          | meta_value            |
+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|  190143 |    5410 |Issue              | 201                   |
|  190141 |    5410 |volume             | 2                     |
|  190140 |    5410 |pages              | 105-109               |
|  190139 |    5410 |authors            | Onger, M., Jaluth, K. |
|  190144 |    5410 |publication_date   | 17 January 2016       |
|  190136 |    5410 |journals           | Nature Medicine       |
|  190135 |    5410 |link_to_pubmed     |                       |
|         |         |                   |                       |
+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

The code i have used is very similar as the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746720/inserting-a-multi-dimensional-php-array-into-a-mysql-database) and can be seen below

```
    $metadata = implode(', ', array_shift($publications));
foreach($publications as $publication){
    foreach ($publication as $key => $metadata){
        $key = array_keys($publication);
        //$publication[$key];
        }
 $new_metadata[] = "(" . implode(', ', $publication) . ")";

}
```

how do i get the key and values?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Couple of `foreach`es with an INSERT nested in them, simplez. What specific part are you stuck with?

Comment: @splash58 i have edited the post/question for a snapshot of the code

Comment: is `meta_id` autoincrement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `meta_id` is an autoincrement field, then

```
foreach($publications as $publication) {
    // Get post_id and remive it from array
    $post_id = $publication['post_id'];
    unset($publication['post_id']);
    foreach ($publication as $key => $metadata) {
       // Below a query. I only print it, you need to execute it
       echo $query = 'insert into table (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
                      values ($post_id, "' . $key . '",  "' . $metadata . '")';
        }
}
```

Comment: brilliant stuff @splash58. Thats what i was looking for.I never thought of a solution in the same way you thought.....Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with 1 query.
You have to run the loop of the array, and in each line run INSERT mysql.